# What is the best C# collection with two keys and an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, prism

I've got a **MenuManager** class to which each module can add a key and and element to be loaded into the main content:

```
private Dictionary<string,object> _mainContentItems = new Dictionary<string,object>();
public Dictionary<string,object> MainContentItems
{
    get { return _mainContentItems; }
    set { _mainContentItems = value; }
}
```

So the customer module registers its views like this:

```
layoutManager.MainContentViews.Add("customer-help", this.container.Resolve<HelpView>());
layoutManager.MainContentViews.Add("customer-main", this.container.Resolve<MainView>());
```

So then later to bring a specific view to the front I say:

```
layoutManager.ShowMainContentView("customer-help");
```

And to get the default view (first view registered), I say:

```
layoutManager.ShowDefaultView("customer");
```

And this works fine.

However, I want to eliminate the "code smell" with the hyphen which separates module name and view name, so I would like to register with this command:

```
layoutManager.MainContentViews.Add("customer","help", this.container.Resolve<HelpView>());
```

**But what is the best way to replace my current Dictionary, e.g. what comes to mind are these:**

- `Dictionary<string, string, object> (doesn't exist)`
- `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string,string>, object>`
- `Dictionary<CUSTOM_STRUCT, object>`

The new collection needs to be able to do this:

- get a view with module and view key (e.g. "customer", "help" returns 1 view)
- get a collection of all views by module key (e.g. "customer" returns 5 views)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strictly meeting your criteria, use a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` ;

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();
...
object view = dict["customer"]["help"];
Dictionary<string, object>.ValueCollection views = dict["customer"].Values;
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853141/collection-requiring-two-keys-to-a-unique-value-in-c-sharp), a good way to represent a 2-key dictionary in .NET 4 is to use the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx/) class:

```
IDictionary<Tuple<K1, K2>, V>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like a composite key into the dictionary, rather than two keys. I would recommend setting up a simple structure to represent this key:

```
struct Section {
   string Area { get; set; } 
   string Area2 { get; set; }

   // override ToHashCode, Equals and implement IComparable.
}
```