# Collection requiring two keys to a unique value 

Tags: c#, collections

I was wondering if anyone knew a good way to store data such that it would be indexed with two keys.  Basically, I need something like a table (top-row is key1, left-column is key2, letters are values returned from indexing):

```
[ ] [1] [2] [3] [4]
[1] [A] [B] [C] [D]
[2] [B] [E] [F] [G]
[3] [C] [F] [H] [I]
[4] [D] [G] [I] [J]
```

I could easily implement this as a multidimensional array, but since half the table is always identical, it seemed redundant.  So far, the best solution I can come up with involves a 2 Dimensional list, with the second dimension being a variable length, while forcing either the larger or the smaller of the two keys to be indexed first.  This turns the table into:

```
[ ] [1] [2] [3] [4]
[1] [A]
[2] [B] [E]
[3] [C] [F] [H]
[4] [D] [G] [I] [J]
```

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Edit: I may have figured out a solution on my own.  See comments.

Comment: your description isn't clear. I have no idea what that first picture (with the A, B, C, etc) is supposed to convey.  maybe instead of drawing pictures, you could use english to describe what it is you want to store, and how the stored data relates to the keys.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have just figured it out though I haven't tested it.  I just need to use a Dictionary with the key as a custom struct containing my two integer values used to index.  I would also need to override the equals operator for the struct, to match the fact that order is independent for the key-values.  I'm going to go with this route for now, let me know what you think of this.  Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what I would have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, char>
```

unless your table will be very large.

Comment: +1 It is disappointing that `Tuple` uses boxing during the calculation of `GetHashCode` for value types so its use as a dictionary key is not quite ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running .NET 4 you should look at the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class.

`IDictionary<Tuple<K1, K2>, V>` - This is the proper way to represent a 2-key dictionary.