# Force all values in a dictionary to be unique?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to maintain a mapping between enum values, and a multi-value type (name+number). e.g.

- ABC : {"john", 123}
- DEF : {"paul", 234}
- GHI : {"ringo", 345}

I planned to do this using a `Dictionary` of some type but strictly speaking not only the keys should be unique, but the values too - it's like a bi-directional dictionary.

Then I need to be able to write a method `MyEnum lookup(string name, int number)` which I'd planned would call `.Single(x => x.Value.name == name && x.Value.number == number)` But I'm struggling to find the right types and apparently the `KeyValuePair` returned cannot be null which is a problem if there is no match.

What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: Can you check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438060/c-sharp-dictionary-type-with-unique-keys-and-values

Comment: And Here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary/255638#255638 , This could be marked as duplicate.

Comment: The second part of my question remains but perhaps I should raise that as a separate question.

Comment: I'd consider using list of `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>`. Then you can simply run `list.Where(t => t.Item2=="John" && t.Item3=="123")`

Comment: But KeyValuePair can be nullable. Just declare the type as KeyValuePair<string, int>?.